# Effect of resistor on the attached circuit

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, component-selection

I have a circuit board that I am trying to repair. I have identified that the following components are bad. ICS801 and RS816 (0.65 ohm resistor +- 5%). I could replace ICS801 but could find an exact replacement for RS816. I am curious about the effect a lower (0.62 ohm) or a higher (0.68 ohm) resistor might have on the operation of the circuit.
[image]

Comment: Why not give us a clue what the board is for, add a hyperlink to the datasheet for the chip, what you think that portion of the board is for, etc.? Please edit your question to add in the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.  They are within the tolerance band.  But if you use a replacement that is at the end of that band you need to measure it to ensure the actual resistance is within the tolerance range given.

Answer (score 0):

The IC appears to be a switching regulator, so it's a good bet that the "CS" pin is a current sense function. The value of the resistance used here will be somewhat critical. It would be safer to go higher in resistance (reduced current) than to go lower, and 0.68 Ω is only 4.6% high anyway. The only danger is that the power supply will not be able to develop the same peak output power, but presumably there's more than enough margin in the original design anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a TV offline AC-DC SMPS controlled by this IC.

This resistor is used to sense the IC internal FET current to determine the phase for cutoff. Burnout failure suggests some part of the unit , perhaps the backlight brightness, demanded too much current or there was another component failure or an overvoltage transient on the grid.

- use the 0.68 Ohm
  If you find a problem, related to 5% low voltage, you can shunt this with  20x this value to get 0.65. I would turn down the backlight for ease to the eyes which will reduce the power load.
  This will regulate to a lower voltage output which means it may consume less power.

(from datasheet)

The primary current is sensed by the external series
resistor R Sense inserted in the source of the integrated
CoolMOS ® . By means of Current Mode regulation, the
secondary output voltage is insensitive to the line
variations. The current waveform slope will change with
the line variation, which controls the duty cycle.
The external R Sense allows an individual adjustment of
the maximum source current of the integrated
CoolMOS ®